# Create New Observations in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a panel data set where my panelid is a combination of two variables, country and job_id, and I have 13 periods. There are 5 countries and 16 job_ids.

My data is a balanced panel where each panelid has 13 periods.

However, one of the countries (USA) has no observations for two job_ids (12 and 16). How do I create 26 more observations for the missing pairs (13 for USA-12 and 13 for USA-16)?

I tried tsfill,full but that did not help.

Comment: Why do this? The only point to doing so is the absent values are non-missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `fillin` to create missing observations such that your panel dataset is fully balance, albeit with missing values.

Here is an generic example:

```
clear
input str3 country float year
"USA" 1
"USA" 2
"USA" 5
"CAN" 1
"CAN" 2
"CAN" 3
"CAN" 4
"CAN" 5
end

gen data = runiform()

fillin country year
```